# Disable Facebook Like/Comment functionality for app Facebook posts

Tags: ios, facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disabling comments or likes on a specific post made via the Facebook API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6820576/disabling-comments-or-likes-on-a-specific-post-made-via-the-facebook-api)

I'm creating an app which posts to Facebook through both actions and wall posts, and I would like to be able to disable the ability for Facebook users to like/comment on the posts. I see that "can_like" and "can_comment" fields exist if I query user actions, and by default are both set to true; is there a way to set them to false when posting?

Comment: @Igy - Right you are. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.